# Get the ID of the text field using a virtual keyboard JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard

I found something abnormal in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/FE4tu/23/). In fact I want to get the ID of the text field; I added an id to the input text and I tried to get the ID with the visible attribute(in the Keyboard) but I found a problem; The first time when I click on the text field nothing happens and when I click another time on a new text field I get the last id where I clicked. 
However, with the accepted attribute(in the Keyboard too) everything is working perfectly.

Could you tell me what happen ?

[Keyboard source](http://mottie.github.com/Keyboard/)

Code :

```
$('.num').keyboard({
    layout: 'num',
    restrictInput: true,
    preventPaste: true,
    autoAccept: true,
    visible : function(){
      ID = $active.attr('id');
      alert(ID);
    },
    accepted : function(){
      ID = $active.attr('id');
      alert(ID);
    },
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'attr' of null

Comment: What debugging tools you used ?

Comment: Just opened the console via F12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overthinking the problem. Use `this` instead:

```
visible : function(){
  ID = this.id;
  alert(ID);
}
```